Can Polkit rules script effectively make <allow_any> the same as <allow_active>?
The .policy files in /usr/share/polkit-1/actions can have a different value for for <allow_any> than that of <allow_active>, or may not even have <allow_any> defined. My goal is that without editing the .policy files themselves (which will be overwritten by app updates), effectively tell Polkit

"Always use the same value for <allow_any> as that of <allow_active> in the .policy file."

Is this possible with a .rules file in /etc/polkit-1/rules.d?
